# R how to extract part of text based on presence of specific word(s)

Tags: r, text

'size' Column of my data set contains text like

```
row_1 =  "Small size From 3 mm long when unfed to 9 mm when fully engorged" 
row_2 =  "Tiny some microscopic Red mite only 0 4 mm diameter Worldwide many different"
row_3 = "Small spiders body length about 10 mm"

size = c(row_1, row_2, row_3)
```

How can I extract the data in a new column say 'new_size' as under

```
size_1 = '3mm, 9mm'
size_2 = '4mm'
size_3 = '10mm'

new_size = c(size_1, size_2, size_3)
```

I have seen the substring methods but am unable to figure out the way to pick up the size from varying text in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Numb_Extract <- function(string){
    unlist(regmatches(string,gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*",string)))
   }
row_1 =  "Small size From 3 mm long when unfed to 9 mm when fully engorged" 
p<-as.numeric(Numb_Extract (row_1))
print(p)
```

Comment: This function will give you arrays with the numbers in each sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Use `regmatches/gregexpr`.

```
regmatches(size, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]mm", size))
#[[1]]
#[1] "3 mm" "9 mm"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "4 mm"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "10 mm"
```

If you want a vector, `unlist` the result.

```
size_n <- regmatches(size, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]mm", size))
unlist(size_n)
#[1] "3 mm"  "9 mm"  "4 mm"  "10 mm"
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  It has done the trick. Appreciate such a quick response. Will also try and learn more about regmatches / gregexpr.